# How to use the names in a GraphQLEnumType as the defaultValue of a GraphQL query argument?

Tags: graphql, graphql-js

When defining a query in a schema, how do I refer to a value of an GraphQLEnumType declared previously, to use it as the default value of an argument?

Let's say I've defined following `ObservationPeriod` GraphQLEnumType:

```
observationPeriodEnum = new GraphQLEnumType {
  name: "ObservationPeriod"
  description: "One of the performance metrics observation periods"
  values:
    Daily:
      value: '1D'
      description: "Daily"
    […]
}
```

and use it as the type of query argument `period`:

```
queryRootType = new GraphQLObjectType {
  name: "QueryRoot"
  description: "Query entry points to the DWH."
  fields:
    performance:
      type: performanceType
      description: "Given a portfolio EID, an observation period (defaults to YTD)
                    and as-of date, as well as the source performance engine,
                    return the matching performance metrics."
      args:
        period:
          type: observationPeriodEnum 
          defaultValue: observationPeriodEnum.Daily ← how to achieve this?
      […]
}
```

Currently I'm using the actual `'1D'` string value as the default value; this works:

```
        period:
          type: observationPeriodEnum 
          defaultValue: '1D'
```

But is there a way I could use the `Daily` symbolic name instead? I couldn't find a way to use the names within the schema itself. Is there something I overlooked?

I'm asking, because I was expecting an enum type to behave as a set of constants also, and to be able to use them like this in the schema definition:

```
        period:
          type: observationPeriodEnum 
          defaultValue: observationPeriodEnum.Daily
```

---

Naïve workaround:

```
##
# Given a GraphQLEnumType instance, this macro function injects the names 
# of its enum values as keys the instance itself and returns the modified
# GraphQLEnumType instance.
#
modifiedWithNameKeys = (enumType) ->
  for ev in enumType.getValues()
    unless enumType[ ev.name]?
      enumType[ ev.name] = ev.value
    else
      console.warn "SCHEMA> Enum name #{ev.name} conflicts with key of same
        name on GraphQLEnumType object; it won't be injected for value lookup"
  enumType

observationPeriodEnum = modifiedWithNameKeys new GraphQLEnumType {
  name: "description: "Daily""
  values:
    […]
```

which allows to use it as desired in schema definition:

```
        period:
          type: observationPeriodEnum 
          defaultValue: observationPeriodEnum.Daily
```

Of course, this modifier fullfils its promise, only as long as the enum names do not interfere with GraphQLEnumType existing method and variable names (which are currently: `name`, `description`, `_values`, `_enumConfig`, `_valueLookup`, `_nameLookup`, `getValues`, `serialize`, `parseValue`, `_getValueLookup`, `_getNameLookup` and `toString` — see definition of `GraphQLEnumType` class around line 687 in https://github.com/graphql/graphql-js/blob/master/src/type/definition.js#L687)

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into this. My enum:

```
const contributorArgs = Object.assign(
  {},
  connectionArgs, {
    sort: {
      type: new GraphQLEnumType({
        name: 'ContributorSort',
        values: {
          top: { value: 0 },
        },
      })
    },
  }
);
```

In my queries, I was doing:

```
... on Topic {
  id
  contributors(first: 10, sort: 'top') {
    ...
  }
}
```

Turns out you just don't quote the value (which after thinking about it makes sense; it's a value in the enum type, not an actual value:

```
... on Topic {
  id
  contributors(first: 10, sort: top) {
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Matthew Herbst, thanks for looking into this and sharing your experience – which relates to stating an enumerated literal value in a GQL query (that is, at «runtime»).

My question was however about the *schema declaration*: how to access one of the enumerated values, using a symbol rather that duplicating the literal value, while declaring the schema itself? – that it, at «schema design time», rather that «query-time / runtime».

Answer (score 0):

It's [possible](https://launchpad.graphql.com/v5rwljk73) to declare enum values as default inputs via the schema definition language, but it looks like you are only using the JS library APIs.  You might be able to get to a solution by taking a [look at the ASTs](http://astexplorer.net/#/gist/212005bbbf9a37a0ab8c425aed78ddf8/aa9b8a064859ea1ffd4deac27bce02dbb2494262) for the working example and [comparing that with the AST](http://graphql.org/graphql-js/utilities/#astfromvalue) from what your JS code is producing.

Sorry not a solution, but hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

I found [a pull request](https://github.com/graphql/graphql-js/pull/674) adding a method `.getValue()` to enum types, which returns `name` and `value`. In your case this call:

```
observationPeriodEnum.getValue('Daily');
```

would return:

```
{
  name: 'Daily',
  value: '1D'
}
```